# Migrate WSE to WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, wse

```
 using Microsoft.Web.Services2;
 using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security;
 using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.Tokens;
 using Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509;

 public void ConfigureService(string username, string password, string certKey)
 {
        var service = new WebServicesClientProtocol();

        service.Url = url;

        service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(new UsernameToken(username, password, PasswordOption.SendPlainText));

        var store = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
        store.OpenRead();

        var cert = store.FindCertificateBySubjectString(certKey)[0];

        var clientToken = new X509SecurityToken(cert);

        store.Close();

        service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(clientToken);

        var signature = new MessageSignature(clientToken);
        service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(signature);
}
```

This is just initialization of the WebServicesClientProtocol, rest is just calling endpoints.

This is the code that is used to communicate with a service. Can it be written in just WCF to not use WSE?

I tried

```
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        var address = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
        var client = new ServiceSoapClient(binding, address);

        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
            StoreName.My,
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
            certName);

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

But it's not working, I just get

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Access to the operation is not present.
  at RecieversNamespace.Framework.ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[] extensions, Boolean throwOnException)
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Access to the operation is not present.

When I add service endpoint, I'm not sure how to setup bindings to replicate the code above. Specifically the MessageSignature part.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do? What do you mean by WSE?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Web.Services2 (WSE). What I'm trying to do is ditch that and only use the WCF APIs to call the service.

Comment: Does the service expose a wsdl file?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. I add the service reference, but after that I need to setup bindings to replicate the code above but I'm not sure how

Comment: What happens if you call the service using the wcf client now? *But it's not working* does not really describe in enough detail...

Comment: I just get System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Access to the operation is not present.